# ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused between laptop and raspberry pi using python

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi

I am a beginner in socket communication and I wanted to test this code.

I wrote the same code but changed the host in the server to s.gethostname() when both the client and server were on my laptop and worked normally.

server: Laptop

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = ''
port = 62402
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
while True:
  clientsocket, address = s.accept()
  print(f"connection from {address} has been established!")
  clientsocket.send(bytes("Welcome to the server!","utf-8"))
```

client: raspberry pi

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 62402
s.connect((host,port))
msg = s.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode('utf-8')
```

Error

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
 File "/home/pi/Desktop/testting/client.py", line 6, in <module>
  s.connect((host,port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Error 111] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection refused tells me that [the target] is not accepting the connection.
I don’t think ´socket.gethostname()´ can possibly return the laptop’s hostname in its current form.
´print()´ what it returns - I’d bet it’s the local machine’s hostname (the one creating the connection).

Once you know where you’re connecting to, Things that could go wrong:

- Is your target listening for a connection on port 62402?
- Will its firewall allow such traffic in?

Comment: I don't understand what should I do? when I print(host) in the client I get raspberrypi and when I write that in the server I get the same error 111

Comment: The code on the pi needs to specify the hostname of the server (´laptop’?).

Comment: it didn't work I got the hostname of the server and it was "DESKTOP-TKAVCD7", then I used this as the host in the client and I got NameError: name 'DESKTOP' not defined.

Comment: I also tried to put in the client host = 'DESKTOP-TKAVCD7' and it gave me socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Comment: Try by IP address, or put that name (+ the IP) in the pi’s /etc/hosts file

Comment: I used the IP address only and it worked thanks man

Comment: Glad you found it - don’t forget to accept the answer 